# how to change audiotrack to ROBOTIC voice android?

Tags: java, android, voice, voice-recording

How can i change audiotrack that has been recorded to ROBOTIC voice android.

```
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            sampleFreq,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                            bufferSizeInBytes,
                            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Comment: can some one tell me that how can i save this track as robotic sound